# What dialect is "just from + Ving"?

Tags: dialects

I have been hearing this construct recently:

> just from + Ving

For instance:

- I'm just from eating [...]
- You're just from swimming [...]

This structure certainly isn't part of *standard* English, if there is such a thing. What dialect does this phrasage belong to?

Comment: Are you permitted to say who you have heard this form from?

Comment: The number of Google hits for "X's just from eating" (X = he, she; I and they with adjustments) are tiny. With "X 's/'m/'re just from swimming", zero. But they're transparent, catchy,  and may well catch on. They sound vaguely Scottish English (cf "It needs painted").

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the usage has no supporting references, and is extremely rare in Google data.

Comment: *This structure certainly isn't part of standard English,* I'm not so sure... it conforms to {prepositon + substantive = modifier}.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to find several online references to the popular use of “I’m just from ... eating/coming/going/seeing“. In all cases they appear to mean “I have just been ...” or “I have just come from ...”.

I have heard the construction only rarely in Scotland. “I’m just from seeing Moira”. More often, but still infrequently, it would replace *from* by *after*, as in “I’m just after doing my shopping” or “I’m just after eating my dinner”.

Comment: I think I've heard this in Wales.

Comment: @DavidGarner *I think I've heard this in Wales* What does "this" refer to?

Comment: In England *“I’m just after doing my shopping”* = All I want to do is my shopping".

Comment: @greybeard. Yes indeed. The joy of regional variations.